# What to include when signing an API request

Tags: c#, oauth, authorization

If I have a complex object that is been sent as an API request (for example Order below), should I include all the properties when generating the signature or should I use just a subset?

I am asking because I am unclear and from looking at other API's the requests parameters are flat and simple

```
public class Order
    {
        public string Id { get; set; }
        public string ClientIdentifier { get; set; }
        public IEnumerable<OrderItems> OrderItems { get; set; }
        public long timestamp { get; set; }
        public string signature { get; set; }
    }

public class OrderItems
{
    public string ItemId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<decimal> PriceBands { get; set; }pes
            more types



}

and so on ....
```

Comment: What has this gotta do with OAuth?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You first need to understand what the signing of the message prevents to understand what data should be included in the request. Here's a list of the 2 main things that signing the requests block attackers from being able to do.

1. With a signed request the password is kept safe and an attacker cannot use the information in the query to sign another request. This is helpful if the attacker can see the request being sent to the server.
2. The attacker cannot modify any data in the request that has been used to generate the signature without invalidating the signature, causing the request to be refused by the server.

Number 2 has a catch to it. It only helps protect the data that is part of the signature. If you leave any data out an attacker could change that data and send a different message than the message you sent. This is why when signing a request **all** of the request data needs to be included: The full URI including the domain, headers, querystring parameters, and any posted data such as XML or JSON.

Answer (score 0):

As hinted by naveen in the comment above, your question does not seem to be a an OAuth question directly:

Looking at the (quite good) explanation of the OAuth flow at http://hueniverse.com/oauth/guide/authentication/ leads to the conclusion that all parameters in an OAuth request need to be used in signing the request because the server will also take all parameters (by definition) to validate the signature, so my suggestion is to *use all parameters for signing*, too ;)

**But (as a side note):**

Your code shows a complex data strutcture which should be submitted, so this raises some more questions: how do you encode the data to be transferable via HTTP? How does the server implementation look like (is it your own implementation or a given service)?

Assuming that you serialize the data to XML or JSON to be used as a request parameter, you'll get "just a string" for the data. This data - used as a request parameter - will completely be used for signing as mentioned above.

I'd also suggest using an Open-Source OAuth client implementation. A good place to start looking for one is the Twitter Client Library page at https://dev.twitter.com/docs/twitter-libraries#dotnet because Twitter uses OAuth for 3rd-party access to its API and the libraries (OAuth components like Hammock) are stable.

Comment: It may not be a direct OAuth question, but I am looking for guidance on how I would sign this type of request using OAUth. Do I include all  request parameters which would mean traversing through all the request types and added them? U suggest serializing the data to one string (e.g JSON) and using this. Why don't all API's (e.g.twitters REST API) do this then?

Comment: At some point you need to convert your request object to some named request parameter(s) that can be transfered via HTTP. And you need to include all parameters, because the server will do the same when authenticating the request. The Twitter REST API is supposed to do the same, because it has named parameters, too.

Comment: It also might be helpful if you could give some more information on how you are actually doing the request (which kind of HTTP library do you use), and how you are converting the request object to HTTP parameters for the actual HTTP request.

Answer (score 0):

As it was already pointed out you need to figure out what attacks you want to prevent.

Usual approach to case when data you are submitting is sensitive is to use HTTPS (SSL) to communicate with the server. In this case you don't need to encrypt/sign data itself, any plain protocol including sending JSON is OK.

If you want to prevent unknown clients to post the data use [mutual SSL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mutual_authentication) which will allow you to limit what client can talk to server.

If you want to verify data is not tampered with over HTTP - sign whole data block... But it is much harder to implement correctly that using existing SSL connection. Check out http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2011/09/27/keep-it-secret-keep-it-safe.aspx

Answer (score 0):

One other thing you could include in the signing data (though it would need to be supported by the API) would be a UTC time stamp.  The API would check the provided time stamp and if it is outside of the expiration window, the request would be invalid.  Also, since it’s included in calculating the signature it can not be modified without invalidating the request.  This will effectively give the signed request a lifespan so it can not be reused by an attacker later.