# How signature validation would be checked on server side?

Tags: api, hash, signature, sha

Sorry, It may be posible few things are repeated in my question.

I have gone through some documentation/discussion [signing an API request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9950812/what-to-include-when-signing-an-api-request) and [twitter signature documentation](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/auth/authorizing-request)

As per the discussion here [signing an API request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9950812/what-to-include-when-signing-an-api-request) With a signed request the password is kept safe and an attacker cannot use the information in the query to sign another request.

But for signature generation uses SHA-1 non reverting hash function.

My Question is:- 
If signature used to authorizes /authenticate client request, how that signature used on server side to check and validate the user request?